# How to make Intellisense/autocompletion work with VSCode/Volar when using the provide/inject functionality with custom plugins in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vue-composition-api, volar

Disclaimer: This project does NOT have Typescript, and migrating to it would be a huge task. Although if there are no better solutions, then I wouldn't mind if somebody answered how to solve the problem with Typescript without having to adapt the *whole* project to it.

The project is built using Vite

---

I have a plugin `@/plugins/ckie.js`:

```js
export default {
  install: (app, options) => {
    const ckie = {
      test: () => { // The test method
        console.log('The ckie plugin is working!')
      },
    }

    app.provide('ckie', ckie)
  },
}
```

My `main.js`:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import ckie from './plugins/ckie'

createApp(App)
  .use(ckie)
  .mount('#app')
```

And when I use it in a component:

```html
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'

const ckie = inject('ckie') // Here VSCode didn't know what plugins (strings) can be injected
const test = ckie.test // Here Intellisense didn't show any hints for the test method
</script>
```

[image: Evidence of Intellisense not working]

[image: Evidence of Intellisense not working #2]

*Yes, I tried restarting the Vue server, reloading the VSCode window.*

Comment: A better autocomplete is one of reasons to use TS, and VSC heavily relies on it. Use your own composable instead of `inject`, then you probably can add types to it without affecting the rest of the project. You can try JSDoc comments, or a single .d.ts file next to .js, can't say which way will work for VSC